How to get (#document (url)) in <object>
I don't know how to get (#document (url)) under <object>.
I want get that URL at variable, then use .
Is it possible at jQuery and console ?
I try this, but I think it's not what I want.
ex)
<object id="ext_obj_1" type="text/html" data="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">Not loading</object>

If I action this code in browser, devTool(F12) monitor is that.
<object id="ext_obj_1" type="text/html" data="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
    #document (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Main_Page)
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        ~ ~ ~
</object>

Then if I click any keyword in wiki(embeded screen by <object>), monitor change that.
<object id="ext_obj_1" type="text/html" data="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/">
    #document (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Encyclopedia)
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        ~ ~ ~
</object>

So I want how to get (#document (url)) under <object>.
Is it possible at jQuery and console ?
